# View tsv table as html with row and column titles fixed

Tags: python, html, css, visualization, csv

I'm trying to visualize a large table in HTML. The origin is a tsv table. I looked for packages to do that automatically but in the end I managed to create a python code that creates the required HTML code. I'm having trouble getting the right visualization.

I have divided the output into three tables that overlap. I want the column and row titles to become fixed, so when you navigate through the results you always know to what they correspond. This is what I've got so far. I think it only need minor modifications in the css.

```
f = open('output/overview_table.html','w')
print>>f,'<HTML>'
print>>f,'<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />'
print>>f,'<div class="container">'
print>>f,'    <div class="tableparent">'
print>>f,'            <table class = "table rowtitle">'
print>>f,'                <tr><td>Logo</td></tr>'
for locus in all_locus:
    print>>f,'                <tr><td>'+locus+'</td></tr>'
print>>f,'        </table>'
print>>f,'            <table class="table columntitle">'
print>>f,'                 <tr>'
print>>f,'                     <th></th>'
for indiv in records:
    print>>f,'                 <th>'+indiv+'</th>'
print>>f,'                 </tr>'
print>>f,'            </table>'
print>>f,'            <table class="table content table-striped">'
for indiv in records:
    print>>f,'          <tr>'
    for locus in all_locus:
        if locus in records[indiv]:
            print>>f,'<td>'+format(len(records[indiv][locus]))+'</td>'
        else:
            print>>f,'<td>NA</td>'
    print>>f,'          </tr>'
print>>f,'            </table>'
print>>f,'            </div>'
print>>f,'            </HTML>'
f.close()
```

and the css can be viewed with some example output at:

**Last version**
http://jsfiddle.net/Jg5vr/25/

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

If anyone is interested, in the end I just used [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/)

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your CSS.

First, you've made the wrong things fixed. Your content is fixed, and so are your column titles, but your row titles aren't, so scrolling either vertically or horizontally only scrolls the row titles. You want to scroll only the content, leaving the titles fixed, so you want to remove `position:fixed` from `.content` and add it to `.rowtitle`.

Second, you've laid out your content so it sits on top of the titles. Just change its placement.

Meanwhile, unless you need to work with really old browsers, why not use a [`thead`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/thead.html) for your table headers instead of a separate table?

Finally, do you really want the headers fixed to the *page* rather than to some parent object? If you search for "CSS fixed header" you should find lots of examples of how to create a container that can be laid out anywhere on the page that holds an absolute header area and a scrollable body area. [This one](http://www.cssbakery.com/2010/12/css-scrolling-tables-with-fixed.html) looks like a pretty complete example.

Comment: Thanks for your corrections. The problem is that in addition to fixed headers I also want the left-most column or row title to become fixed. I wasn't able to find such code.
The one you suggested is very interesting but only fixes headers. In addition I do not know how to change the placement of the content table.

Comment: @biojl: The basic idea is to create _two_ div wrappers—a container, and a scrolling area. You put the headers and the scrolling area inside the container, and you put the main table body inside the scrolling area. That way, instead of being fixed to the edges of the browser page, they're fixed to the edges of the container, which can then be positioned (and zoomed and scrolled, if necessary) normally.